# Internal Server Error (500) when Ajax loads PHP script

Tags: php, ajax

I am building an message board application using Javascript and PHP. When I try to load a php script via Ajax, I get a 500 internal server error. If I load basic text instead of php, the Ajax call works fine and the text is displayed.

Anyone know why the server would have trouble with this?

Here's my php file:

```
<?php
    //Get input from my form
    $from = $_POST["guestbook_from"];
    $msg = $_POST["guestbook_msg"];
    $today = getdate(date("U"));

    recordMessage($from,$msg); //external php function, creates database record

    //Print some html
    echo("<p>");
    echo($msg);
    echo("</p>");
    echo("<h4>");
    echo($from);
    echo("<br />");
    echo("<small>");
    echo("posted on ");
    echo($today[month]);
    echo(" ");
    echo($today[mday]);
    echo(", ");
    echo($today[year]);
    echo("</small>");
    echo("</h4>");
?>
```

Comment: Do you have access to the apache error logs? You can possibly find more information about the error in the logs.

Comment: Also, set up a php.ini file to record any PHP errors that may be generated.

Comment: Are you using POST when doing it Ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the HTTP status code, you need to investigate the server's error response too. The response body might be having error messages, if any!

You got to use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). Enable the Console (or Net) tab and you will all HTTP requests and responses.

[image: console]